# Rails Routing Error: uninitialized constant UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I've looked through throughout stack overflow and I can't find the answer I need. I get the following error: uninitialized constant UsersController

```
users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find( params[:id] )
    end
end
```

show.html.erb

Please help.

> uninitialized constant UsersController

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

```
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url          
new_user_session_path   GET /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new
user_session_path   POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session_path   DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy
user_password_path  POST    /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#create
new_user_password_path  GET /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password_path GET /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
PATCH   /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
PUT /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration_path   GET /users/cancel(.:format) users/registrations#cancel
user_registration_path  POST    /users(.:format)    users/registrations#create
new_user_registration_path  GET /users/sign_up(.:format)    users/registrations#new
edit_user_registration_path GET /users/edit(.:format)   users/registrations#edit
PATCH   /users(.:format)    users/registrations#update
PUT /users(.:format)    users/registrations#update
DELETE  /users(.:format)    users/registrations#destroy
user_profile_path   POST    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)   profiles#create
new_user_profile_path   GET /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)   profiles#new
edit_user_profile_path  GET /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format)  profiles#edit
GET /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)   profiles#show
PATCH   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)   profiles#update
PUT /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)   profiles#update
DELETE  /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)   profiles#destroy
users_path  GET /users(.:format)    users#index
POST    /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path   GET /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path  GET /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path   GET /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
PUT /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
contacts_path   GET /contacts(.:format) contacts#index
POST    /contacts(.:format) contacts#create
new_contact_path    GET /contacts/new(.:format) contacts#new
edit_contact_path   GET /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)    contacts#edit
contact_path    GET /contacts/:id(.:format) contacts#show
PATCH   /contacts/:id(.:format) contacts#update
PUT /contacts/:id(.:format) contacts#update
DELETE  /contacts/:id(.:format) contacts#destroy
about_path  GET /about(.:format)    pages#about
root_path   GET /   pages#home
```

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"5"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None

This is the only error message I'm gettting: 
Routing Error
`uninitialized constant UsersController`

```
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:70:in `controller_reference'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:60:in `controller'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:39:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: The name of your file, controllers shouldnt be plural

Comment: It isn't. That was a mistake on my part when I typed it

Comment: Can you post the full trace, the full file path and name, the routes file?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post the full trace (i.e., the full error message) and file path/name?

Comment: @RyanK I hope what I've added is what you requested. I didn't see a way to format

Comment: That is your list of routes (and you can format it by clicking on the "{ }" button when you create/edit a post). What we need is the full error message that you see that tells you something is wrong.

Comment: @RyanK I just figured out what you meant by "full trace". I've added it

Comment: @lurker that's not the name. I incorrectly added the 's' when I typed in message

Comment: Can you post the contents of config/routes.rb not the output or rake routes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change you le filename from

> users_controllers.rb

To

> users_controller.rb

Rails use the filenames to find controllers in your app.